# How to label individual cells with mosaicplot in R

Tags: r, graphics, labeling

I was wondering how to  label individual cells when using `mosaicplot()`. And no, I cannot use `mosaic()` from the `vcd` package.

`test<-matrix(c(21,54,4,21), 2,2)`

`mosaicplot(test)`

This produces the plot I need, but short of labeling all the cells manually with the `text()` command, I can't figure out how to label them. Thanks!

PS: This is my first post. Sorry if I don't conform to standard norms.

Comment: You may have a look at [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228326/mosaic-plot-with-labels-in-each-box-showing-a-name-and-percentage-of-all-observa/20230060#20230060)