# Display single cases in mosaic plot in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem:

I need to create a mosaic plot but want to display the number of cases for each mosaic, as total numbers per country differ. The plot is based on the following data:

```
   1 - not agree 2 3 4 5 - fully agree
DE             6 2 0 0               1
ES             5 3 1 1               0
FR             6 3 1 2               0
SE             4 3 0 0               0
```

I used the following code:

```
> mosaicplot(Q1, col=c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "green4"),
+          las = 1,
+          main = "There is no need to do anything about it.",  
+          ylab = "",
+          xlab = "Country")
```

Giving me this graph:

[image]

Now I would like to divide the first red bar into six bars of the same colour, as there were 6 votes in Germany a.s.o. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Would you considering putting a label in each box to indicate the number?

Comment: Yes, definitely, but I don't know how. Any idea?

Comment: @lawyeR: Sorry, it's been ages, but I'd still appreciate your help!

Comment: I found a solution using ggplot2. Thank you.

Comment: Congratulations.  I was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228326/mosaic-plot-with-labels-in-each-box-showing-a-name-and-percentage-of-all-observa.  Why don't you post your solution as the answer so others will be able to learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the procedure explained here: 
https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/

Only I had to use two data frames, one for the percentages and one for the absolute values.

Both data frames went through the same calculations. Whilst dfm1 created the chart, dfm21 was used for the labels:

```
p2 <- p1 + geom_text(aes(x = xtext, y = ytext,
 label = ifelse(dfm21$value == "0", paste(" "), paste(dfm21$value))), size = 3.5)
```

Comment: I tried adding an [image](https://itscloud.uni-kassel.de/index.php/apps/files_sharing/ajax/publicpreview.php?x=1674&y=898&a=true&file=%252FQ1%2520(2).png&t=59b85b07863596e82ed531bf8eacc02f&scalingup=0), but it seems my reputation is too low :-(